# Restoring AWS RDS MySQL from Snapshot

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

We are looking at upgrading our MySQL version on RDS. All of the information I can find about restoring RDS mentions that a new instance is created.

When restoring RDS from a snapshot, does the endpoint change? I imagine a whole new can of worms is created if the endpoint is changed.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.MySQL.html)? You can just upgrade the database in-place.

Comment: That's...not the problem I'm having. I know that, but if it goes poorly, what is best practice for rolling back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=81015).

> If you delete your DB Instance, and later create a new DB Instance (or
>   restore it from snapshot) in the same region with the same
>   DBInstanceIdentifier as your original one, it will have the same
>   endpoint DNS name as your original DB Instance.
>
> Note that the endpoint DNS name (like
>   mydb.cwuz5lta310x.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com) is permanent through a
>   restart, even if you upgrade the instance class. However, the IP
>   address that the endpoint's DNS name resolves to may change over time.

Comment: Thank you much, Tim.